# sql not find record from field even if I copy-paste its content

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, where-clause

I'm working with MySql on a table `message` with one column `message`, it contains a very long html string.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT message FROM message LIMIT 1;
```

And the result is something like:

```
...
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 5%; width: 90%;">/
/<div style="background: #666; width: 100%;"div>/
...
```

Now if I copy the previous result and paste in a query like

```
SELECT message FROM message WHERE message = 'content copied before'
```

I get 0 result, but I expect the one got before!

Is it a **line break** issue?

How could I solve this?

Comment: Try double quotes around the where clause after the = as in WHERE message = "content pasted before" which I assume is the previous returned value from your select. The DIV has quotes in it already which is causing it to come back empty.

Comment: problem could be line break. what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Sanj In my db I save some of html content and I'd like to make a query that check if exactly that content was saved before or not, in order to avoid saving it again

Comment: @apesa I cannot double quote the message because, as you say, DIV has quotes in it and so I get syntax error... :(

Comment: `%` is a meta-character in SQL strings, AFAIK. Try escaping it as `\%`. Might not be the only one though, try starting from something like `<div>` and adding one special character after the other.

Comment: Try to save the message into a file and use [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function: `WHERE message = LOAD_FILE('/path/to/file.html')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to validate the content earlier saved, you can use md5 hash.

```
SELECT md5(message) FROM message LIMIT 1;
```

Take this "md5-hash" and use it like below

```
SELECT message FROM message WHERE md5(message) = <md5-hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [QUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function.

> mysql> SELECT QUOTE('Don\'t!');
>
> ```
>     -> 'Don\'t!'
> ```